# Error while building with erdpy for crowdfunding

Tags: linux, rust, multiversx

I'm doing like the tuto in elrond doc [here](https://docs.elrond.com/developers/tutorials/crowdfunding-p1/) I'm currently getting this error when I try to build:

```
Compiling elrond-wasm-derive v0.25.0
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
--> /home/aimeric/elrondsdk/vendor-rust/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/elrond-wasm-derive-0.31.1/src/lib.rs:4:12
|
4 | #![feature(proc_macro_quote)]
|            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
error: could not compile `elrond-wasm-derive` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
CRITICAL:cli:Build error: error code = 101, see output.
```

verion with `rustup show`:

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/aimeric/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (directory override for '/mnt/1C5C20C64606690B/github/elrond-cagnotte/test_smartcontract/crowdfunding')
rustc 1.63.0-nightly (c35035cef 2022-05-30)
```

I already tried with both version but is not working I still have the same issue.
Do someone have an idea of how can I fix this issue?

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I am stuck with this issue myself and the rustup default nightly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Write to command line:

```
rustup default nightly
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).